# How do you view your top % of tags?

Tags: support, statistics

I remember seeing percentages associated with your tag scores, but can't seem to find them anymore.

For example: "Top 30% in [Java]"

Does anyone know where this is?

Comment: careers.so has that.

Answer (score 2):

Such a thing is only available in Stack Overflow Developer Story, which is part of [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab) (formerly Careers).

You can see it in [your own Developer Story tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current):

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

You could write a query using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer(SEDE) to find this out, but in this case [Tim Stone's already done it for you](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50844/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag).